# Creating custom CCActions for cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

What is the best way to create custom actions in coco2d?

I would like to create a custom action that will create a cartoony squash animations on my game objects. Do I just subclass the CCFiniteTimeAction class and override the update method?

Any examples or links would be appreciated.

Also, within my custom action, I would like to use the CCScale action. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is pretty much all the magic. An example can be found at http://getsetgames.com/2009/09/23/custom-cocos2d-action-for-animating-an-atlassprites-texturerect/

It is possible to use CCScale action. I think if you import and use it it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

just write a custom method that returns a CCSequence

something like:

```
-(CCSequence)squash{
id action1=....//define action
id action2=...2nd action
...
return [CCSequence actions: action1, action2,..., nil];
}
```

and you just call `[mySprite runAction:[self squash]];`

with this solution you can change absolutely everything about the sprite (even call function inside the sequence (using CCCallFunc)

[here](http://cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/actions_transformations_and_effects.html) is the link i use for documentation regarding what i can do (yes..it's written in java but there are the same methods in iphone cocos2d)

if you run into any problem..post you code and i'll look through it